# How to escape double quotes in in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have the following code that I believe I need to escape in thymeleaf.

```
th:required=""
```

It throws the following error:

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: ""`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't that you need an escape, it's that you need an expression that Thymeleaf can interpret as true or false. `th:required="${expression}"` tells it to include the `required` attribute if `expression` is true and leave it out otherwise. If you want to include it unconditionally, drop the Thymeleaf namespace and just include an ordinary `required="required"`.